# Get row from one table, that has its id in other table with condition(don't know how to name it)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm afraid, that I've asked my question in title wrong...

I have two tables in database, that are related to this question

Products

- product_id
- name
- etc.

Categories

- id
- product_id
- category_id

I need to create two queries.

One to get products id that have `product_category = 1` AND `product_category = 2` AND `product_category = 3` [...].

And the second one is to get `products id` that have `product_category = 1` OR `product_category = 2` OR `product_category = 3` [...]

I've tried everything that I've learned, but with no effects
What kind of query should I use?

EDIT:

Here's some sample rows and expected results

Products

```
ID | Name 
------------
1  | Prod_3
------------
2  | Prod_4
------------
3  | Prod_5
------------
4  | Prod_6
```

Categories

```
ID | ProductID | CategoryID
----------------------------
1  |     1     |     101
----------------------------
2  |     1     |     102
----------------------------
3  |     1     |     103
----------------------------
4  |     2     |     102
----------------------------
5  |     2     |     103
----------------------------
6  |     2     |     108
----------------------------
7  |     3     |     121
----------------------------
8  |     3     |     111
```

I Want to select `Name` from `Products` table. This products should be in `Categories` table, and have specific `CategoryID`

Example1:

```
Select `ID`, `Name` From `Products`

WHERE IN `Categories`.`ProductID` = `Products`.`ID`

AND (`Categories`.`CategoryID` = 103 AND `Categories`.`CategoryID` = 102)
```

This should Result in:

```
ID | Name 
------------
1  | Prod_3
------------
2  | Prod_4
```

Example2:

```
Select `ID`, `Name` From `Products`

WHERE IN `Categories`.`ProductID` = `Products`.`ID`

AND (`Categories`.`CategoryID` = 108 OR `Categories`.`CategoryID` = 121)
```

This should Result in:

```
ID | Name 
------------
2  | Prod_4
------------
3  | Prod_5
```

Comment: @user3013821 are you sure product_id in Categories table? I think Product table has CategoryId.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using MySQL

Comment: @LukStorms I've updated my question with some samples

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need something like that:

```
select distinct p.ID, p.Name
from Products P 
  inner join Categories C on c.ProductId = p.ID 
where c.CategoryID in (108, 121)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having` to get the products that have *all* the categories:

```
select p.ID, p.Name
from products p join
     categories c
     on c.productid = p.id
where c.categoryid in (102, 103)
group by p.id, p.name
having count(*) = 2;  -- number of items in the `in` list
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with:

```
SELECT a.product_id FROM `product_categories` a

INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_categories WHERE category_id = 1655) a1 ON 
a1.product_id = a.product_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_categories WHERE category_id = 1605) a2 ON

[...]

a2.product_id = a.product_id

WHERE a.category_id = 1575
```